# Confirm black hot white hot one double pole 20amp for well

Tags: wiring, circuit-breaker, 240v, well-pump

I bought a home on a well. Several years later I am putting in a transfer switch for my gas gen. I have a good understanding of wiring and various wiring needs. Ok - my well is on a double 20amp with one hot black on one pole and a white wire on the other pole. Wells are typically two or three wire 240v.

As I look at the encased wire coming in I can’t tell that the wire used was for two hot config.

I am 90% sure this is just me overthinking… that the white IS a proper second hot - otherwise the WELL wouldn’t have been working all these years. I don’t see any indicator that the original owner put red tape or black tape on the white wire.

I like to think 4 times before tinkering with things like this which is why I am asking for community input.

Comment: We can't tell you with high confidence what your white wire is--only what's typical. Get out your multimeter and check voltage to ground.

Comment: Do not install one of those 6/8/10 circuit transfer switches if you can possibly avoid it.  #1 it is very hard to put on some loads, #2 it's *dangerous* with MWBCs, #3 it's illegal with GFCI/AFCI. #4 they cost a fortune and #5 aren't legal on many circuits because of #1-3.   If at all possible, install a generator interlock, which cures #1-5, is much easier to wire, and lets you choose loads to be on generator anytime, not at install time.

Answer (score 2):

White is often used as the second hot on 240v circuits that do not need a neutral.

Mainly to save money when a third wire is not needed.

Older style switch loops also used white as a hot.  These are the circuits that really need the red/black tape/mark.

240 volts usually are assume the white is hot, but marking is still recommended.

Just because the white is not marked, does not mean you cannot mark it.  Just turn off the breaker first.